# HTML5 geolocation info window not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I need to create info-window out of this code, I'm lacking of application logic and totally new to programming i use this [open-source code](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLMapChat/)

This code add users to the map along with their marker

```
    function loadMarkers(data) {
    for(key in data) {
        var user = data[key];
        xmartlabschat.addUser(user);
        markers[key] = getMarker(user.lat, user.lng, user.name);
    }
}
```

I tried to use the basic code for info-window

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(user.name);
markers[key].addListener('click', function(){
        infoWindowMe.open(map,markers[key);
```

However this code turns all marker into same name with the user instead of different names since im clicking other users marker

Please Help
[Here the screenshot I took](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqhku.jpg)

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: yes when I try to make my own info-window the window isn't above the marker and even though i click different marker the name shows mine instead and not the user marker

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI i already added some screenshot of what is the error

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Geolocation info-window not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549121/html5-geolocation-info-window-not-working)

Comment: duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Hope this helps.

```
var locations = [
['Location name', LAT, LON],
['...', ..., ...],
//...
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(LAT, LON),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i; 
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var lat = locations[i][1];
    var lng = locations[i][2];
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
    }); // generates all the markers
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            zIndex: 1000;
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]); // replace locations[i][0] with which data you want to show
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i)); // generates corresponding info-window
}
```